# How to require UNIQUE PASSCODE before a user can submit a google form questionnaire

Tags: passcode

Can you provide the steps to do in requiring validation code which is assigned per user before he can continue on with the forms?

How to set up the form and the sheet?

Comment: Scenario:  i will assign 2 entry code and save it in my google sheet like:
Column 1:  UNIQUE CODE
Column 2   NAME

When the user fill up the form, the assigned CODES Column 1 and 2 should match.  Otherwise, he can't proceed

Comment: Update your question instead of commenting on yourself.  Also, it seems to be a google form question, so tag it as such.  No idea on how to help you though.